# Debugging Microsoft Bot Framework C# source in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, botframework, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to step into the Microsoft Bot Framework C# SDK source while debugging in Visual Studio 2017+?
Are symbols required, and if so are they available? (I have searched but not yielded much information)

This could make some aspects of bot debugging remarkably easier, so any information is appreciated!

Comment: AFAIWA the bot framework is open source/you can download the source and add it as a project in your solution rather than reffing eg a nuget pkg? https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk / https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet

Comment: Actually, Bot framework is open source. I wonder which nuget package you are using.  You can enter the bot framework nuget package on the `nuget.org`  and then click `Source repository` to get its source code and then debug it directly and you can get what you want.

Comment: Thanks you two, downloading the source and creating a package with symbols worked well!

Comment: @Traw , glad to know that it helps you handle the issue. I have added an answer for you and you can check it, accept it. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debugging Microsoft Bot Framework C# source in Visual Studio

**Bot framework** is open source and you do not worry about not being able to access internal methods.

You could download the source from [this github link](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet) and then you get its pdb file so that you can step into it.

**Just download the source,create a local package with symbols and then we can debug it.**

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what do you mean by creating a local package with symbols? Perhaps a tutorial link or a video recommendation?

If I understand correctly, you would first want to download and open the csproject found in the github repo, then run some nuget commands against that project?